# access file in mips using mars tool

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

I'm trying to do some access on file using mips instruction.
I want to read file line by line not all of the file at a time so this code(1) does not work.

Also I want to write to the file and not overwrite!
Can any one help me?

Code:

Open a file for writing

```
li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, file      # board file name
li   $a1, 0        # Open for reading
li   $a2, 0
syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0      # save the file descriptor
```

Read from file

```
li   $v0, 14       # system call for read from file  
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor   
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer to which to read  
li   $a2, 40     # hardcoded buffer length  
syscall            # read from file
```

Close the file

```
li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file  
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close  
syscall            # close file
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read file line by line not all of the file at a time so this code(1) does not work.

Read chunks of data into a buffer (e.g. a few kilobytes). Then process that buffer line-by-line (by looking for linefeed characters), and read more data from the file when you've reached the end of the buffer.

> Also I want to write to the file and not overwrite!

Set the flags (`$a1`) to 9 when opening the file (syscall 13). This corresponds to "write-only with create and append" (see [this MARS syscall reference](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)).

Comment: li   $v0, 14       # system call for read from file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer to which to read
li   $a2, 4096       # hardcoded buffer length 256*16
syscall            # read from file

 li $v0, 4   # 
 la $a0, buffer  # buffer contains the values
 syscall    # print int
       
      
        lb      $a1 , buffer($0)
        
I tried to do what u just suggested to me 
but i can't implement it !!!!!!!!!
caN any one help me !!
i wanna to save it as hex from buffer

Answer (score 0):

it's work thx alot :)

```
.data  
fin: .asciiz "file.txt"      # filename for input
buffer: .space 128
buffer1: .asciiz "\n"
val : .space 128
.text

################################################ fileRead:

# Open file for reading

li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, fin      # input file name
li   $a1, 0        # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
syscall            # open a file 
move $s0, $v0      # save the file descriptor 

# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  6  # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file

li  $v0, 4          # 
la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
syscall             # print int

lb $t1 , buffer

# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  6  # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file

li  $v0, 4          # 
la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
syscall             # print int

## sh  $t5 , val($0)    #sw    $t5, theArray($t0)

# Close the file 

li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file
```